# C++ , exe has stopped working during execution

Tags: c++

I'm made a small program that merges two arrays using merge sort algorithm but surprisingly it stops working when executed...it doesn't have any compilation errors.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<array> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    // below are declarations of two single dimensional arrays and two variables

    int n1,n2,t1,t2,t3;
    int l1 [5] = {2,1,4,3,5};
    int l2 [5] = {8,6,7,9,10};
    int l3 [10];

    n1 = l1[4] - l1[0] +1;
    n2 = l2[4] - l2[0] +1;   


   //below are the declaration and initialization of two pointers

     t1 = l1[0];
     t2 = l2[0];
     t3 = l3[0];


      while((n1>0) && (n2>0) )

     {

         if (l1[t1] < l2[t2])
         {

             l3[t3] = l1[t1]; 
             t1++;
             t3++;

             n1--;
             cout<<l3[t3]<<endl;

          }
          else
            l3[t3] = l2[t2];
          t2++;
          t3++;
          n2--;

     } 

 }
```

I still didn't decide the output of the program

Comment: Run your code under a debugger to see where the exception occurs.

Comment: Did you miss some brackets on your else? I edited the formatting so that your code is readable but to me it looks like you are missing some brackets.

Comment: Maybe everything after `else` is supposed to be in the `else` block?

Comment: i added the braces for the else block but its still stopping the execution.

Comment: Then its time to single step your code in your debugger.

Comment: One thing I will tell you is that t1 .. t3 are not pointers and that the values that they contain are not what you expect. Although if they were pointers your indexing with l1[] .. l3[] would be totally wrong.

Comment: Yes, `t1 = l1[0];` should probably be `t1 = 0;` And `cout<<l3[t3]<<endl;` should come before `t3++`.

Answer (score 1):

You're very confused about pointers. This:

```
n1 = l1[4] - l1[0] + 1;
```

takes the *value* of `l1[4]`, subtracts the *value* of `l1[0]`, then adds `1`. You seem to think `l1[4] - l1[0]` is going to give you the number of elements in the array, less `1`. What you actually want here is:

```
n1 = sizeof l1 / sizeof l1[0];
```

Similarly, this:

```
t1 = l1[0];
```

doesn't make a "pointer" - `t1` is just an `int` which contains the *value* of `l1[0]`, not it's address. As pointed out in the comments, even if it were a pointer, you wouldn't be able to use it as an index. What you actually want is:

```
t1 = 0;
```

Finally, this:

```
while( (n1 > 0) && (n2 > 0) )
```

is going to stop after making it through just one of your arrays. What you want is:

```
while( (n1 > 0) || (n2 > 0) )
```

although this will break if `l1` contains any elements higher than `l2`.

Here's a modified version of your program which implements your algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int l1[5] = {2, 1, 4, 3, 5};
    int l2[5] = {8, 6, 7, 9, 10};
    int l3[10] = {0};

    int n1 = sizeof l1 / sizeof l1[0];
    int n2 = sizeof l2 / sizeof l2[0];
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0;

    while ( (n1 > 0) || (n2 > 0) ) {
        if ( l1[t1] < l2[t2] ) {
            l3[t3++] = l1[t1++];
            --n1;
        }
        else {
            l3[t3++] = l2[t2++];
            --n2;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof l3 / sizeof l3[0]; ++i ) {
        std::cout << l3[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./ms
2
1
4
3
5
8
6
7
9
10
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Obviously, as implemented, your algorithm merges the two lists, but if they are not originally sorted then you won't end up with a sorted list. If you do want to end up with a sorted list, then you have some more work to do. Also, as noted above, your algorithm in general will not work correctly for most arrays.